# What does fseek do?

Tags: c, io, fseek

I'm new to C and am using fseek. My question is, what exactly does it do?

eg: `fseek(FILE *stream, -1, SEEK_CUR)` will read 1 character backwards, so is it already at the end of the file?

Does that mean `fseek(FILE *stream, 0, SEEK_CUR)` does nothing?

And how do we apply the functions after `fseek` to a data structure?

Comment: `fseek` does not `read 1 character backwards`.  It doesn't read anything; it just sets the position in the file.

Comment: There are some side effects, so `fseek(..., 0, SEEK_CUR)` is not a no-op.  But it does not change the position in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm new to C and am using `fseek`. My question is, what exactly does it do?

`fseek` sets the file position indicator for the stream pointed to by `stream`.  The new position will be given by the offset in conjunction with the flag:

- For `SEEK_SET`, the offset is relative to the start of the file.
- For `SEEK_CUR` the offset is relative to the current indicator position.
- For `SEEK_END` it's relative to end-of-file.

> eg: `fseek(FILE *stream, -1, SEEK_CUR)` will read 1 character backwards, so is it already at the end of the file?

It may be at beginning, in the middle or at the end, the current position is where it is right now. If the indicator is at the end of the file it will be moved one byte back.

It does not read characters, as stated, it positions the indicator to the desired position, by offset, from it's current position as explained above.

> Does that mean `fseek(FILE *stream, 0, SEEK_CUR)` does nothing?

In practical terms it does nothing visible, because the offset is 0 it does not move the indicator, it just places it at the same position. It does clear the end-of-file status (resets the `EOF` flag [as mentioned by @rici](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66158015/what-does-fseek-do/66158535?noredirect=1#comment116965287_66158535)).

From **C11 N1570 §7.21.9.2**

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> int fseek(FILE *stream, long int offset, int whence);
> ```
>
> **Description:**
>
> > **2** The `fseek` function sets the file position indicator for the stream pointed to by `stream`. If a read or write error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and `fseek` fails.
> > **3** For a binary stream, the new position, measured in characters from the beginning of the file, is obtained by adding offset to the position specified by `whence`. The specified position is the beginning of the file if `whence` is `SEEK_SET`, the current value of the file position indicator if `SEEK_CUR`, or end-of-file if `SEEK_END`. A binary stream need not meaningfully support fseek calls with a `whence` value of `SEEK_END`.
> > **4** For a text stream, either `offset` shall be zero, or `offset` shall be a value returned by an earlier successful call to the ftell function on a stream associated with the same file and `whence` shall be `SEEK_SET`. 
> > **5** After determining the new position, a successful call to the `fseek` function undoes any effects of the ungetc function on the stream, clears the end-of-file indicator for the stream, and then establishes the new position. After a successful `fseek` call, the next operation on an update stream may be either input or output.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> > **6** The `fseek` function returns nonzero only for a request that cannot be satisfied.

Comment: `fseek(stream, 0, SEEK_CUR)` resets the EOF flag. It's not the simplest way to do that, but it does do it. (Useful if you're writing something like `tail -f`.) On many systems (eg. Linux), it also lets you know whether or not `stream` is seekable but I don't think that behaviour is guaranteed by any standard.

Comment: @rici, correct, it clears the end of file status. Maybe the side effects William Pursell is mentioning.

Comment: @anastaciu so fseek just points to a position in a data structure? To read a character in a file, can an alternative to fseek be fscanf ?

Comment: @No_Name, it makes the indicator point to some position in stream, the next reads performed by some reader function (like fscanf) will be performed from that point on, `fscanf` actually reads the contents of the stream and advances the position of the indicator to the point where the read stops, they don't do the same thing, though you can use fscanf to advance the indicator the read number of bytes, but if the goal is just to move the indicator, the right tool is `fseek`.